# Check next character for speciality

Tags: java, io, filereader

I'm writing a bit of code which reads input from a text file and prints out tokens and their label. I've run into a problem, however. If the code reads in letters, it should ideally check the next character to see if it is another letter or a special character, for example:

```
abcde=123;
```

How do I tell the program to look ahead and see if the next character is another letter, equals, number etc.
Now, is there any way within that if statement to say 'if the next character is not a letter, print " = TEXT\n", else continue'?

If this question confuses, I'm very sorry (it's 1 am here) and I will offer more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the next character is NOT a digit. Check out the Character API. It has a method isDigit(). Basically, if the next character is NOT a digit then it is either a special character, space or a letter.

Hope this helps you a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, using the `Character.isLetter(character)` method.  This method will return `true` if the argument is a letter and `false` if it isn't.

A [link to documentation on `Character`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Comment: If you're assuming ASCII only you only need the if check (I'd be somewhat surprised to find non-characters in the range 97-122), but then why would you want to assume such a thing? The character methods are MUCH better for these things.

Comment: Voo, I used the `Character.isLetter()` method for the letter check.  The entirety of that code, sans the `Character.isLetter()` check was provided by the OP.

Comment: Voo, noticed the OP edited question so I edited my answer to remove the code example as it may be confusing to people who didn't see the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll answer your question, but then offer what I think is a better way to accomplish what you're doing.

If you wrap your Reader in a BufferedReader you can mark the point where you are, get the next character and reset to jump back to the previous character so that on the next iteration you'll read the character again:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
br.mark(1);
int firstByte = br.read();
br.reset();
```

The other way to accomplish this and avoid having to look forward is to append each character to a StringBuilder. Then when you need the entire number because you hit a non-digit you have the entire number in the StringBuilder. If you re-use the same StringBuilder and just clear it when needed this should be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, Java also has a [PushbackInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) class. Sometimes this is just what is needed to deal with lookahead -type problems.